# Object made of cubes looks different based on the distance in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, graphics, shading

I made a ***"Wall"*** from basic Unity3D cubes. They are placed **tightly** so the wall looks like **one big rectangular prism**.

If I look at it from **close distance**, it looks as it should be: **one big rectangular prism**.

But if I start **moving backwards, away from the wall**, the **cubes' edges become visible**:

[image]

And this whole thing happens in a **circular way**.

- If I just start moving backwards from the wall,
- first I start to see the cubes' edges just at the further parts of the object, and then the **pure white** circle starts shrinking, the edges become visible at bigger and bigger parts of the object.
- then the **blurrier** edges appear at the further places and the previously appeared **sharper** edges circle starts shrinking as well. **(this phase is shown on the image above)**

This should be some kind of shading optimization, like mipmap, right?

How can I fix this? **I want the wall to be seamless from all distances.**

**Update:**

- Changing the shader to `Unlit > Color`, **fixes the issue.**
- This thing only occurs on the **lit side** of the wall. The shadowy side of the wall, *(which isn't lit directly by the directional light of the scene)* is rendered normally.

Comment: So when you are close to the objects it just likes like a big cube that is all white, right? Could you try to change the material's shader to something like `Unlit -> Color` and see if this makes the lines disappear? It's not a "proper" solution, but at least you'd know its the shader's fault.

Comment: @TomTsagk It didn't help.

Comment: I've just tested it on Unity and this is not the default behaviour. Have you changed any lighting/material settings that could have caused this? Although unlikely, could you try making a new project and testing the same thing (to rule out its not something machine-specific).

Comment: I exported the wall, then imported to a blank project, and the same problem occurs. You can download it from here, don't mind the missing scripts, network components, etc: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3n3ggcj4kt3eas/wall.unitypackage?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I mean, could you try making a new project, and create a handful of cubes and stack them together to have the same effect as this project? Did you create the wall in Unity with cubes, or is it exported from a 3D software (Blender/Maya etc)? Unfortunately I can't download anything at the moment.

Comment: I just put down Unity cubes in a row, placed them into a parent container, CTRL C CTRL V them so I could make a floor from the rows, then put those "Row"s into another container called "Floor", so I could stacks the floors, making a higher object.

Comment: Now I started it all over, in an empty project: placed a "unit cube" (scale = (1,1,1), i dont know what international that term is), multiplicated a few times, placed them tightly (like x = 1,2,3,4,5), aaaaaand: the result is the same.

Comment: If TomTsagk is not able to reproduce this in their copy of Unity, then this might be specific to your graphics card. It would be worth checking whether your graphics driver is configured to automatically apply anti-aliasing or other custom quality enhancements - those settings might be creating these artifacts if they're not well-matched to what Unity's expecting.

Comment: @TomTsagk Sorry for my previous answer, I mislead you, I somehow managed to mess up changing the shading to Unlit. I changed the question description based on this.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that scaling the wall to your desired dimensions will not suffice, and you need it in the multi-cube form?  (Interesting problem btw, +1)

Comment: I guess there is a workaround, if you use a big cube to represent the wall using the LOD system

Comment: Yes, they need to be separated, so big structures' voxels can be invidually damaged and destroyed.
@MuhammadFaizanKhan can you elaborate please?

Comment: "big structures' voxels can be invidually damaged and destroyed" does not imply "they need to be separated" - most voxel games that look like they're built out of individual cube objects are actually rendering combined meshes that span many logical cubes. When you damage an individual voxel (you can determine which logical voxel got hit using its grid position, even when it doesn't have its own separate collider/object), the mesh for that group is updated.

Comment: The should be some easier way... This is a pretty big workaround and makes everything more complicated. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix it, with the help of the **official Unity Forums**. (*20 minutes after posting, there was already an answer)*

**I just had to increase the (Shadow) Bias of my light source.**

*(Increasing it from 0.05 to 0.3 fully removed all the edges.)*

[image]

Comment: Keep an eye out for Peter Panning when increasing this setting - this is where a narrow object in contact with the ground has its shadow come "unglued" from.its base, so it appears to be hovering slightly.